# HTML with JavaScript, submit button

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I'm trying to write a simple widget to measure Net Promoter Score. This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="NPSstyle.css"/>
    <h1>Net Promoter Score<h1>
        <p class="question">How likely are you to recommend this tool to a friend or colleague?</p>
<form id="myForm">

    <button type="button" id="button1">1</button>
    <button type="button" id="button2">2</button>
    <button type="button" id="button3">3</button>
    <button type="button" id="button4">4</button>
    <button type="button" id="button5">5</button>
    <button type="button" id="button6">6</button>
    <button type="button" id="button7">7</button>
    <button type="button" id="button8">8</button>
    <button type="button" id="button9">9</button>
    <button type="button" id="button10">10</button>
    <button type="submit" class="input submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<p class="explanation">Not likely............................................................Very likely</p>


<script>

var userRating

document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 1;
}
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 2;
}
document.getElementById('button3').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 3;
}
document.getElementById('button4').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 4;
}
document.getElementById('button5').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 5;
}
document.getElementById('button6').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 6;
}
document.getElementById('button7').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 7;
}
document.getElementById('button8').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 8;
}
document.getElementById('button9').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 9;
}
document.getElementById('button10').onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.id + " was clicked")
    userRating = 10;
}


</script>
```

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get Submit to work. I want the user to press the button that represents their score, and then press submit to register their score. Right now, I just want their score to be displayed in console when they hit submit, but eventually it is going to be getting saved to a server and this will just be a widget that pops up over their screen in browser. I'm starting out making this thing in a vacuum to help myself learn. I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction or giving me a hint. This is my first taste of JavaScript so I'm still learning. Thanks!

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough information. How does the score get registered? Do you need to submit the score to the server? Do you want to trigger a page load or do you want this to happen in the background? etc.

Comment: I just edited my question to be more clear, sorry!

Comment: Why aren't you using radio buttons for the choices?

Comment: Would that be better? I'm new to JS and DOM

Answer (score 1):

In the same way that you added `onclick` handlers to the buttons, you can add an `onsubmit` handler to the form.

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() {
    console.log(userRating);
}
```